# write MongoDB client driver equivalent code in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have written the following code to connect to `mongodb` and get a database named `admin`.

```
async function dbConnectMongoDB() {
  const client = new MongoClient("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017");
    
  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log('connected to Mongo');
    const db = client.db("admin");
    console.log(`connected to database ${db.databaseName}`);
    const collections = await db.collections();
    collections.forEach(c => {console.log(`got collection ${c.collectionName}`)})
  } catch(exception) {
    console.log(`something bad happened in dbconnect: ${exception}`);
  } finally {
    console.log("closing database connection");
    client.close();
  }

}
```

How do I write the same using `Mongoose`? I can't find equivalent functions for `finally` and to get the `admin` database.

So far, I have written the following function but it isn't working

```
async function dbConnectMongoose(){
  const connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017");

  connection.on('open',function() {
    console.log('connected to Mongo'); // I SEE THIS
    new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {
      console.log('listDatabases succeeded'); //I DONT SEE THIS 
      // database list stored in result.databases
      var allDatabases = result.databases; 
      console.log(`list of databases ${allDatabases}`);//I DONT SEE THIS 
//I WANT TO GET `admin` database only but can't find function for that  
//I WANT TO GET collections in `admin` database only but can't find function for that   

  });
  })

  connection.on('error', (exception) => {
    console.log(`something bad happened in dbconnect: ${exception}`);
  })
//WHERE DO I CLOSE CONNECTION
}
```